# passport-local-mongoose changePassword function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport-local

I want to have the functionality that user can change their password. 
I've implemented a route (**'/resetPasswd'**) like this:

```
UserRouter.route('/resetPasswd')

.post(function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        user.changePassword(req.body.oldPassword, req.body.newPassword, function (err, user) {
            if (err) next(err);
            res.json('password changes successfully !');
        })
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

this is what I send as the body:

```
{
    "oldpassword": "secret",
    "newPassword": "new"
}
```

But I get this error as response:

```
{
   "message": "user.changePassword is not a function",
   "error": {}
}
```

and this is a picture of my schema:

user schema:

[image: user schema]

I don't think I should declare the **changePassword** function in my schema (since it is provided by the **passport-local-mongoose**, although I added it but still get the same error) What mistake am I making here?

Comment: can you show us your schema and middleware on your schema if you have any?

Comment: Reffer this link http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/ it will be helpfull for you ...

Comment: @turmuka : I've already provided a picture of my schema in my post

Comment: @Syed Ayesha Bebe I've already seen this post, I don't need to implement anything since all the functionality is provided by passport itself. I just don't know how to use it

Comment: please [don't put code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). copy the code and paste here

Answer (score 1):

Someone had the same issue last night actually. Their problem was the package needed to be updated. I would check that you're on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did in my controller handling the reset password,

```
exports.editPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    username: req.user.username
});
await user.setPassword(req.body.password);
const updatedUser = await user.save();
req.login(updatedUser);
req.flash('success', 'Password Changed Successfully') res.redirect('back')
}
```

from the  Documentation  [Passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#asyncawait) ,you first need to get the specific user to update the password , here in my case the current login user , which is available on the **req.user** which we are exposed to , you can use any of the return property to query your collection, using async await i made a variable to hold the return object, in my case 'user',  thereafter i chained the setProperty on it passing in the new password(req.body.password) since it return a promise i await it and assign a variable to it. from here you are good ...Note: since it is a promise it either resolved of reject, handling error can be done by rapping your code in a safe blanket, `try..catch` .  You can read more  [Here](https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

Since `changePassword` is a schema method, it must be used on an instance of a model, not the model itself or the imported passportLocalMongoose.

```
UserModel.findById(req.user._id) 
// I assume you already have authentication and the req.user is generated
        .then(foundUser => {
            foundUser.changePassword(req.body.old, req.body.new)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('password changed');
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

the user object passport sends in callback function is just an object and not a schema instance document object, thus it does not have the changePassword function.

Comment: If req.user is defined then you can use req.user.changePassword() directly to change the password. There is no need to use UserModel.findById(). Passport-local-mongoose defines req.user when a user is logged in.